# Why doesn't the number increase when the function is called?

Tags: python, function, button, numbers, int

In a python script, I want a counter to increase every time you click a button. In my current code, when you click the button the number doesn't increase. What am I doing wrong?

```
import direct.directbase.DirectStart
from direct.gui.OnscreenText import OnscreenText
from direct.gui.DirectGui import *

from panda3d.core import TextNode
clickCount = 0

bk_text = "Times Clicked: " + str(clickCount)
textObject = OnscreenText(text = bk_text, pos = (0.95, -0.95),
                          scale = 0.07, fg = (1,0.5,0.5,1), 
align=TextNode.ACenter, mayChange = 1)



def setText(clickCount):

    addClickCount(clickCount)
    bk_text = "Times Clicked: " + str(clickCount)
    textObject.setText(bk_text)

def addClickCount(clickCount):
    clickCount += 1
    return clickCount

b = DirectButton(text = ("button"), scale=.05, command=setText(clickCount))

run()
```

Comment: it's because you're passing it by copy to the function so the `clickCount` in `addClickCount` is not the global `clickCount`

Comment: You need to assign the return value to something then use that - `something = addClickCount(clickCount)`.   Pretty sure this is a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

As per @wwii comment, try this:

```
def setText(clickCount):

newClickCount = addClickCount(clickCount)
bk_text = "Times Clicked: " + str(newClickCount)
textObject.setText(bk_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `clickCount` is a global variable, what about this:

```
import direct.directbase.DirectStart
from direct.gui.OnscreenText import OnscreenText
from direct.gui.DirectGui import *
from panda3d.core import TextNode

clickCount = 0

textObject = OnscreenText(text = bk_text, pos = (0.95, -0.95),
                          scale = 0.07, fg = (1,0.5,0.5,1), 
align=TextNode.ACenter, mayChange = 1)

def setText():
    count = addClickCount()
    bk_text = "Times Clicked: " + str(count)
    textObject.setText(bk_text)

def addClickCount():
    global clickCount 
    clickCount += 1
    return clickCount

b = DirectButton(text = ("button"), scale=.05, command=setText())

run()
```

Comment: You can't rebind a global variable in a function without a `global` statement. Also you don't want to call `setText()` (with the parentheses) while you're creating the button, just pass a reference to the function without calling it.

Answer (score 0):

In Python `int` objects are immutable. That means you can never modify one in place, only rebind a variable that refers to one integer to instead refer to a different one.

However, normally you can't rebind a global variable from inside a function. Any assignment you make creates a local variable instead of rebinding the existing global variable (and you can't read the old global variable and then later bind a local variable of the same name, the scope of a name is local for the whole function if you ever bind a value to it).

However, Python offers the `global` statement to change the default scope behavior. If you say `global clickCount`, then the variable `clickCount` will refer to a global variable everywhere in the function.

So the obvious fix for your code is to first remove the argument passing from your functions (which were never doing anything useful), and instead use a `global` statement:

```
def setText():
    addClickCount()
    bk_text = "Times Clicked: " + str(clickCount)
    textObject.setText(bk_text)

def addClickCount():
    global clickCount
    clickCount += 1

b = DirectButton(text = ("button"), scale=.05, command=setText)
```

The `addClickCount` function is so short at this point you might consider merging it into `setText`, unless you want to be able to call it separately.